can we prove $0 < q < 1$ implies $0 < 1- q < 1$ algebraically WITHOUT multiplying by $-1$?
can we prove $0 < q < 1$ implies $0 < 1- q < 1$ WITHOUT multiplying by $-1$?
Seems like we can't do it. I know it's true, and it's easy to put together word arguments like "the supremum we can subtract from 1 is 1, which isn't contained in the set q can be, so we've got $1-q > 0$", and then similar logic to say $1-q < 1$
But I'm curious if it's possible to prove this without multiplying through by -1 or using word arguments or if multiplying by -1 is the only way to get there without word arguments.
Is this an abstract algebra concept? (We have to use homomorphisms to do this. I haven't taken abstract algebra.)

Once we get to this level of detail, we have to be very precise about what our axioms are. What rules exactly are you assuming about how $+$, $-$, and $<$ interact?

Maybe I'm not ready for the answer haha. + Is associative, has the additive identity.... - is the inverse of + and < is an ordering that's preserved when the same operation is done on either side? (I guess this wouldn't be true if you allowed multiplication and division by negative numbers and I guess maybe I wouldn't be allowed to have negative numbers in my subtraction if this was the case?)

Though it is a good question. $+1$ from me

At this level of detail, the answer will depend on what exactly your axioms are - that is, what rules you take for granted. Below, I'll give an answer using only the following:

If $x>0$ then for all $y$ we have $x+y>y$.

$(x-y)+y=x$.

For all $a,b,c$ we have $a>b\iff a+c>b+c$.

$0+x=x$ for all $x$.


OK, so suppose $0<q<1$. First we'll show $1>1-q$. This is easy: by our first axiom, we have $(1-q)+q>1-q$, so via our second axiom we get $1>1-q$.
Now we want to show $1-q>0$. Here we use our third axiom to get $$1-q>0\iff (1-q)+q>0+q.$$  But by our second and fourth axioms we know that the right hand is just $1>q$, which we have assumed, so we get the left hand side too.

Admittedly, you might argue that multiplication-by-$(-1)$ is implicit here each time we make use of subtraction. But since the original problem statement involved subtraction, I don't think that's very fair.
